# How do you prove that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ under these conditions?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have a question that I haven’t been able to find a proof for. Hope you guys could help me with it.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable at all points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ except for $(0,0)$. It is know that it is continuous at $(0,0)$ and that the following goes for it-

the limit of both partial derivatives (with respect to $x$ and $y$) approach to $0$ at $(0,0)$, i.e.
$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f'_x(x,y)=\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} f'_y(x,y)=0$

I need to prove that f is differentiable at the origin. I have tried to show prove that the partial derivatives are continuous without success, and I have also tried to get some clue using differentiability by definition at $(0,0)$. Maybe I am missing something.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please Use MathJax

Comment: One possible approach is to show that the partial derivatives are continuous at the origin. It looks like you would just need to show that $f_x(0,0) = 0$ and $f_y(0,0)=0$.